# ayuda con el problema de Tiempo de ejecucion agotado en una query statement Dapper c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms

que tal amigos estoy trabajando una aplicacion con c# usando el orm dapper. en caso es que en siertas ocaciones guardo cierta cantidad de registros en una sola ejecucion, aprox 400 registros. el problema es que en a veces, me lanza una excepcion de el tiempo de ejecucion se agoto, esto pasa alguardar datos y actualizar.

hay alguna manera de alargar el tiempo de ejecucion, sin que me lanze la excepcion. ya que en mi aplicacion lo requiero.

les adunto el codigo.

```
if (transferencia.transferenciaDetalles.Count != 0){
                        conn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO TransferenciaDetalles(EncabezadoID, ProductoID, CodigoPersonalizado, Cantidad, PesoOriginal,Piezas, EsBateo) 
                                                    VALUES( @EncabezadoID, @ProductoID, @CodigoPersonalizado, @Cantidad, @PesoOriginal, @Piezas, @EsBateo)", transferencia.transferenciaDetalles);
}
```

transferencia.transferenciaDetalles es una lista de objetos, este accion tarda algo de tiempo 40 segundos con 400 registros.

```
 foreach (var transferencia in transferencia.transferenciaDetalles)
  {
                            string QueryTransferenciaInventario = @"select
                                                                inv.Id, 
                                                                inv.ProductoID as ProductoID, p.Nombre, 
                                                                inv.CodigoPreimpreso, 
                                                                inv.Peso, 
                                                                inv.SucursalID
                                                                from Inventario as inv 
                                                                inner join Productos as p on p.ID = inv.ProductoID
                                                                where inv.CodigoPreimpreso = @CodigoImpreso
                                                                and inv.Consumido = 0";

                            ProductoInventariado = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Query<InventarioDTO>(QueryTransferenciaInventario, new { CodigoImpreso = transferencia.CodigoPersonalizado }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                            TransferenciaDetalles transferenciaDetalle = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Query<TransferenciaDetalles>("select * from TransferenciaDetalles where CodigoPersonalizado = @Codigo", new { Codigo = transferencia.CodigoPersonalizado }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                            StringBuilder StringQuery = new StringBuilder();
                            string Query = " UPDATE inventario "
                                         + " SET UsuarioUltimoCambio = @UsuarioAlta "
                                         + ",FechaUltimoCambio = GETDATE() "
                                         + ",Peso = @Peso "
                                         + ",SucursalID = @SucursalID ";
                            string Consumido = "";
                            if (chkExterno.Checked)
                            {
                                Consumido = ",Consumido = @Consumido ";
                            }
                            else {
                                Consumido = ",Consumido = @Consumido ";
                            }
                            // validar si el check de externo esta aplicada
                            // si esta aplicado actualizar el campo de consumido y cambiar la sucursalID por el que se envio

                            Query = Query + Consumido + " WHERE ID = @ID ";



                            VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Execute(Query, new
                            {
                                ID = ProductoInventariado.Id,
                                SucursalID = Convert.ToInt32(cbDestino.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                                UsuarioAlta = VariablesGlobales.UsuarioID,
                                Consumido = (chkExterno.Checked) ? true : true,
                                Peso = ProductoInventariado.Peso
                            });
                            // se actualiza el detalle de la transferencia en recibido para que no se acumule en las pantalla de transferencias pendientes para los externos
                            var rows = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Execute("Update TransferenciaDetalles Set PesoEnSucursal = @PesoEnSucursal, CantidadEnSucursal = @CantidadEnSucursal, HuboDiferencias = @HuboDiferencias,Recibido = @Recibido Where ID = @ID",
                            new { CantidadEnSucursal = 1, PesoEnSucursal = ProductoInventariado.Peso, Recibido = 1, HuboDiferencias = 0, ID = transferenciaDetalle.Id });

}
```

En el siguiente, en la iteracion hago un selec, para determinar de que el registro exista. segundo, y en las ultimas 2 hago actualizaciones. pero ahi, dentro del foreach es donde en ciertas ocaciones. lanza la excepcion del tiempo de ejecucion agota, hay alguna manera de evitar ese problema, en alargar el tiempo que demore.
Espero alguien me ayude, gracias.

Comment: podrias poner el error? primero es muy raro que tardes 40 segundos en actualizar 400 registros.. y lo otro que me parece muy raro.. es que los querys los haces de a 1... no los 400 juntos, con lo cual no entiendo porque tenes demoras de tiempo...

Comment: El error sale en ciertas ocaciones, es aleatorio. puede surgir si lo pruebo ahora o no. y el error Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Comment: y estas en un servidor local? algun problema con la base de datos?

Comment: El servidor es remoto

Comment: mmm.. puede ser un problema de red entonces... microcortes.. caidas de paquetes.. firewalls...

Comment: En los métodos de dapper generalmente hay sobrecargas con el parametro timeout, verifica la documentación. Y Dapper no es ORM, mas bien podria catalogarse como micro orm.